# jqgrid guriddo - Cannot read property 'styleUI' of undefined

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid

I set styleUI to default jQueryUI. Everything works fine without actions in navigator. When I try:

```
$('#grid').navGrid(
      '#pager',
      { edit: true} ,
      {
         editCaption: "The Edit Dialog",
         errorTextFormat: function (data) {
            return 'Error: ' + data.responseText
         }
      }
   );
```

Javascript crashes with error :

> Cannot read property 'styleUI' of undefined.

How can I solve this problem?

I have the newest version and include ui.jqgrid.css and jquery.jqGrid.js. I'm doing something wrong but I don't know what

**UPDATE**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="path_to_ui_css_file/jquery-ui.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="base.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="path_to_ui_css_file/ui.jqgrid.css" />
</head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">

           <button id="export">EXPORT</button> 
           <table id="grid"></table>
           <div id="pager"></div>
        <div> 

    <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript">
    <script src="jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript">
    <script src="path_to_js_files/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="path_to_js_files/jquery.jqGrid.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

     <script type="text/javascript">

           $(function() {
              $( document ).ready(function() {

                 $options = [       //OPTIONS WITHOUT COLMODEL
                                 'mtype' => 'GET',
                                 'url' => '...'
                                 'datatype' => 'json',
                                 'height'=> null,
                                 'width'=> null,
                                 'shrinkToFit' => false,
                                 'gridview'=> true,
                                 'sortable' => true,
                                 'autoencode' => true,
                                 'rowNum'=> -1,
                                 'pager' => '#pager',
                                 'viewrecords' => true,
                                 'rowList' => [10, 50, 100, -1],
                     ];
                 $('#grid').jqGrid(options); 

                 $("#button").on("click", function(){

                    $('#grid').jqGrid('exportToCsv'); //WORK CORRECT
                 });

                 $('#grid').navGrid(   //DOESNT WORK
                   '#pager',
                   { edit: true} ,
                   {
                       editCaption: "The Edit Dialog",
                       errorTextFormat: function (data) {
                           return 'Error: ' + data.responseText
                   }
                 }
               );
              });
           });
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Im trying @license Guriddo jqGrid JS - v5.2.1 - 2017-05-01

Jquery is older jQuery v1.8.2

Comment: what do u mean "set styleUI to default jQueryUI" ?

Comment: Only set in jqgrid options 'StyleUI' to 'jQueryUI'. My current options are: {
  "mtype": "GET",
  "datatype": "json",
  "pager": "pager",
  "url": "url",
  "colModel": [
    {
      "name": "id",
      "autoResizing": {
        "minColWidth": 310
      },
      "formatter": "integer"
    }
  ]
}

Comment: i think `jqGrid` is searching for `#grid` if you add more code it would be nice

Comment: Are you sure that you load Guriddo jqGrid? I see you have option in the colMode, autoRewsizing, which is not avialable in Guriddo jqGrid, but maybe in other fork. Can you please post the full code including everything in the page - I mean which libs are loaded, what css and where is your code in the html page.

Comment: You have a lot of syntax errors in your code. I suggest you to use some professionally editor to fix them. The first one is that the `<div class="wrapper">` is not closed correct. Second you have not properly close the script tags and etc . Please try to execute the code posted here in pure html file and you will see the result, since it seems you use PHP. When I fix the syntax errors your code run propery

Comment: This was just example with mistakes. I found solution and it was my mistake. I called navGrid before initialize jqgrid in element. I simple swaped code from beforeInit function to afterInit and everything works fine. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution and it was my mistake. I called navGrid before initialize jqgrid in element. I simple swaped code from beforeInit function to afterInit and everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I was dealing with a child grid when I got this error.  To resolve it, I defined the pager functions using chaining, like this:

```
jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
    colModel: [
        { name: 'Name', width: 200, editable: true },
   //...

}).jqGrid('navGrid','#pager', { edit: true, add: true, del: false},
```